# OS X: trouble with dirent struct attribute of scandir() function

Tags: c, macos, posix, scandir, dirent.h

I'm trying to make a snapshot of a directory, like it described in [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-SW4).

I want to use `scandir()` function. Here it is from documentation:

```
scandir(const char *dirname, struct dirent ***namelist, int (*select)(const struct dirent *),
     int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

I don't understand how to use it properly. Here is how I implement my snapshot function:

```
-(void)createFolderSnapshotWithPath:(NSString *)pathString
{

NSLog(@"snap");
const char *pathsToWatch=[pathString UTF8String];

struct dirent snapshot;


scandir(pathsToWatch, &snapshot, NULL, NULL); // I have a warning here because 
                                              // &snapshot used wrong here


NSLog(@"snap result: %llu | %s | %i",snapshot.d_ino, snapshot.d_name, snapshot.d_type);
// snapshot.d_type returns 0 which means unknown type (DT_UNKNOWN) 

}
```

Here is a `dirent struct`:

```
struct dirent {
    ino_t d_ino;            /* file number of entry */
    __uint16_t d_reclen;        /* length of this record */
    __uint8_t  d_type;      /* file type, see below */
    __uint8_t  d_namlen;        /* length of string in d_name */
    char d_name[__DARWIN_MAXNAMLEN + 1];    /* name must be no longer than this */
};
```

I don't understand hot to proper create `dirent struct` and how to proper use it in `scandir()` function.

All I want from that function is an array that I could use later when I will compare it with another snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scandir()` allocates an array of entries.

So you should declare the 2nd paramter like this:

```
struct dirent ** snapshot = NULL;
```

And after successfully having called `scandir()` you can access its members like this:

```
printf("%s", snapshot[0]->d_name);
```

for example.

If the array along with its entries isn't used anymore, 1st free the entries looping over all and calling

```
free(snapshot[i]);
```

for each entry and finally do:

```
free(snapshot);
```

All this together might look like this:

```
#include <dirent.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct dirent ** namelist = NULL;
  int n = scandir(".", &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
  if (n < 0)
  {
    perror("scandir");
  }
  else
  {
    while (n--) 
    {
      printf("%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);
      free(namelist[n]);
    }

    free(namelist);
  }
}
```

Comment: @flinth: The array is accessed by a pointer to an array of pointers to `struct dirent`. This is by design.

Comment: hi, can you explain me, how can I get a file last modified dates, using `scandir()`. Is it possible? Apple documentation confuses me with this.

Comment: @flinth: `scandir()`is POSIX. Perhaps you might like to read its documentation here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scandir.html